# Install ROS Groovy alongside Boost 1.55

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, boost, ros-groovy, libboost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to install ROS Groovy (but the error also exists with Hydro), but it won't install unless I uninstall my new version of Boost. However, I also want to use the newer Boost library, since only the latest version supports the algorithm I use. I tried `apt-get install`, which complained that I held broken packages, and `aptitude install`, which simply stated that I should remove the new Boost version and let it uninstall the old one.

Any way I can still install ROS with a newer version of Boost?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172790/install-ros-groovy-alongside-boost-1.55/) by [sanchises](https://answers.ros.org/users/18785/sanchises/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-06-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The key issue here is that different versions of boost can't be installed side-by-side, and the ROS binaries depend on the older version of Boost. See [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/170406/ros-hydro-and-boost-148/) for a more detailed explanation.

You can use ROS, but you'll have to compile it from source.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5